# MacOS 12 "can't open file 'pyaudio.py'" issue, has anyone seen and resolved this issue?

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

After running:

```
brew install portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio
```

I get the following error running a python script that calls pyaudio:

> (null): can't open file 'pyaudio.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Is anyone familiar with this error? I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS has built in python 2.7 and pip.
Seems you are executing the script with built in python runtime which doesn’t install pyaudio, because you are install pyaudio with pip3 which belongs to another python runtime.

Try to troubleshoot on terminal with commands will likely show you the macOS python:
“which python” and
“python —version”

run your pyaudio project with

```
python3 yourscript.py
```

if you still encounter issue, check the path of pip3:

```
python3 $(which pip3) --version
```

Then you can validate if the pyaudio library has been installed properly in "site-packages" folder which associated with the runtime.

Comment: Thanks: I have python and python3 both installed. I need to work with both versions at the moment for different projects. This is the result of your suggestions: `which python: /usr/local/bin/python` `which python3: /usr/local/bin/python3` where python2 is version 2.7.15 and python3 is 3.7.0. How can I symlink python3 to run pyaudio?

Comment: Removed the symlink solution, that might break the OS. Just run with python3 yourscript.py

Comment: It points towards an installation error now, I've reinstalled and get: 
    `File "pyaudio.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudio
    File "/Users/{mypath}/pyaudio.py", line 5, in <module>
    pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyAudio'`

Comment: @MariaHernándezGarcía what are you trying to setup? it seems the PyAudio is not setup properly. Check this out (https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/9767512210a1d80a8a0d)

Comment: Thanks! Still no luck: trying to follow those instructions gives me `configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
    file: '/Users/me/.pydistutils.cfg', line: 1
    'include_dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.6.0/include/\n'`

Comment: For what it's worth I've moved on and am using the sounddevice library, which works fine. The issue isn't portaudio but the pyaudio library.

Comment: This seems weird? The last bet is that maybe your setup script of the pyaudio is using venv. Or during the setup of pyaudio some dependencies from PortAudio is missing but didn’t prompt you.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately no luck on this one but at least I have another solution to use a different library.

Comment: Thought I should update this thread: for reasons unknown (probably user-error-related), pyaudio started working after a reboot. I believe the instructions suggested by @Tempo810 on Feb 12 were what resolved this problem.